# Checkbox not setting to true if Case Closed >= 10 Days

Tags: workflow

I have this workflow rule that checks a 'Reply Received' checkbox to true and i want to adapt the logic to not check if the case is closed for more or equal 10 days.

The logic is like this:

```
Email Message: Incoming equals True AND
Case: Status not equal to New
```

I added this new rule to the condition but it doesn't work as i expected:

```
Case: Date/Time Closed less or equal LAST 10 DAYS
```

Can someone help me meet the requirement?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"less or equal" on a date range like this *includes* the last ten days. You want "less than last 10 days" instead. `LAST 10 DAYS` is a date range that includes the last 10 days, so by saying "less or equal", you're including every moment in time that has already occurred. By using "less" instead, the system will check for everything earlier than the last ten days.